# What is the simplest way of receiving and then processing a csv on a website?

Tags: python

Essentially I built an application using Python (specifically Pandas) that reads a csv then performs some actions on it then ultimately produces an output graph.

I wanted to make this application into a website and I have learnt a bit of HTML, CSS and JavaScript to do this. I want the website to mainly do these 2 things

1. Receive a file
2. Process the file using Python then output the image back to the website

What is the best course of action for this problem? Learn Flask? Learn Django? Would I need to learn anything else?

I've already learnt how to create a file uploader for the website using Vue but can't seem to wrap my head around connecting it to a database.

Comment: Flask is great for what you are trying to accomplish. I'd recommend [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) as it is how I got started with Flask.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, leanest solution to just receive data and reply would be to start a `http.server`, see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html. Anything else will be extra overhead, both in terms of learning and running. On the other hand, if this application will grow, learning Flask or Django will have added benefits.

Here I found a quick introductory tutorial on `http.server`: https://www.afternerd.com/blog/python-http-server/

For uploading, take a look at `do_POST` (e.g. here https://pymotw.com/3/http.server/) and look how to handle multipart form uploads (e.g. full example here https://gist.github.com/rctay/25bed284cd4bcc1477f4)